# drracket - can't edit

Tags: scheme, racket

on linux, after install racket, I started drracket, I selected language as "Pretty Big", then press "Run", then I can't input into the editor, even though I could load external files.

Why can't I input code by keybaord?

---

**@Update:**

I reinstalled via `ppa:plt/racket` as suggested in comments, and it has version 6.1.1 now.
but still I can't input anything via keyboard.

There is a **error** tip in shell:

`(process:6651): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0' failed`

Here is the **screenshot**:

[image]

[image]

Comment: What I want to know is why people can even pick Pretty Big as a language option. It seems to cause the most amount of trouble, judging by the questions I see on Stack Overflow.

Comment: More germane to your question, please post a screenshot.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young Works perfectly for me on OS X. Eric, what OS are you on?

Comment: @LePetitPrince I think you meant to ask what distro, since the OP already mentioned Linux.

Comment: @LePetitPrince I am on linux mint mate 17. Maybe my installation has issue. I downloaded the ubuntu version since there is version for mint.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young No matter which language option I choose, it's the same, I uploaded a screenshot.

Comment: Did you install it from [here](https://launchpad.net/~plt/+archive/ubuntu/racket)? If not I recommend uninstalling the current version and using this source.

Comment: 5.3.6 is a tad old. [Download a newer version](http://download.racket-lang.org/). If you have a debian based distro you can add *ppa:plt/racket* and just upgrade your system.

Comment: @Sylwester I installed a new version as you suggested the result is similar...

Comment: @LePetitPrince I reinstalled via ppt, it's a new version now, but problem remains.

Comment: Compiling from source is always an option that is likely to produce an installation compatible with your system's current state. That's the beauty of Linux. It will take some time, but I did it last year on a laptop with 256MB and a Coppermine Celeron running WaryPuppy. T Good luck.

Comment: You should ask this question on the Racket mailing list.

Comment: @LePetitPrince I just use the racket command-line to learn SICP, I  decide to ignore DrRacket now ;)